# TabBar text faded

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, tabs, tabbar

I’m facing the next problem, my Tab's text was fading out long and you couldn't see the last letters.

[image]

```
Widget _tabBar() {
    return TabBar(
      onTap: (tabIndex) {
        setState(() {
          _tabController.index = tabIndex;
        });
      },
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      controller: _tabController,
      labelColor: currentTheme.currentAppTheme.colorAccent,
      unselectedLabelColor: currentTheme.currentAppTheme.tabInactiveColor,
      labelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
      indicatorColor: currentTheme.currentAppTheme.colorAccent,
      indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      indicatorWeight: 4,
      tabs: [...],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I've approached is adding `labelPadding`

[image]

```
labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
```

P.S You can also change Flutter sdk Tab widget method `_buildLabelText` from `TextOverflow.fade` to `TextOverflow.visible`, but it is kinda messy solution